# How do I add temporary properties on a mongoose object just for response, which is not stored in database

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

I would like to fill a couple of extra temporary properties with additional data and send back to the response

```
'use strict';

var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

var TournamentSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    createdAt: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
    deadlineAt: { type: Date }
});

var Tournament = mongoose.model('Tournament', TournamentSchema);

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    var tournament = new Tournament();

    // Adding properties like this 'on-the-fly' doesnt seem to work
    // How can I do this ?
    tournament['friends'] = ['Friend1, Friend2'];
    tournament.state = 'NOOB';
    tournament.score = 5;
    console.log(tournament);
    res.send(tournament);
});

var server = app.listen(3000, function() {
    console.log('Listening on port %d', server.address().port);
});
```

But the properties wont get added on the Tournament object and therefor not in the response.

Comment: Your code works for me... are you sure? Can you add some console.log just before sending response?

Comment: I updated the code to be runnable and with console.log. The log is also without the added properties. How do I add more properties to the response without risking them being added to the databas ?

Comment: @farvilain updated question, I dont think it was clear enough

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Found the answer here: [Unable to add properties to js object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18554350/unable-to-add-properties-to-js-object)

I cant add properties on a Mongoose object, I have to convert it to plain JSON-object using the `.toJSON()` or `.toObject()` methods.

**EDIT:** And like @Zlatko mentions, you can also finalize your queries using the .lean() method.

```
mongooseModel.find().lean().exec()
```

... which also produces native js objects.

Comment: FWIW you can also mongooseModel.find().lean().exec()... which also produces native js objects.

Comment: This comment should be added to the accepted answer.

Comment: @Zlatko I added your comment to the answer