# Can not add property to an object in mongoose function

Tags: javascript, node.js, object, mongoose

I have a function which gets some data from database and binds it to some variable:

```
exports.getAccDoc = function(req, res, send, next) {
var AccDoc = require('../models/accdoc');

AccDoc.find({
   startup_id: req.startup.startup_id
}).exec().then(function(accDocs) {
  vm.accDocs = accDocs; //I'm using vm in my view
  console.log(vm.accDocs); //logs a array that contains one object
  console.log(vm.accDocs[0]); //you know
  vm.accDocs[0].test = 'TEST'; //trying to add some property to the object
  console.log(vm.accDocs[0].test); //logs TEST like it should be
  console.log(vm.accDocs[0]); //logs an object, But it doesn't contain test property
  send(res); //sending vm to view
});
};
```

Why my object doesn't changes after adding `test` property to it?

(I can change existing values of a property though, But can not add new properties)

Comment: Apparently you can't.  See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18554350/unable-to-add-properties-to-js-object

Comment: @PeterVC That was hard to search I think. thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That because the result returned from Mongoose is a Mongoose Object instead a plain javascript object. You need to use [`lean`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-lean) method to get the plain object you can play with.

```
AccDoc.find({
   startup_id: req.startup.startup_id
}).lean().exec().then(function(accDocs) {
  ...
```